Helmet Rejects Localhost Even Though it is Included in Script-Src?
I'm running my node.js web app at:
http://localhost:3000/
I'm getting this error from Helmet:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval'
'unsafe-inline' 'sha256-DFWWwGm2cBwXA13nbn4jDkHCl2Oc/0Z2tKvKkN4NWj4='
http://localhost:3000/
http://localhost:4000/
[.....]". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.

http://localhost:3000/ is listed in the script-src directive. Why am I getting this error?

Helmet maintainer here. From the error message, it looks like you're trying to execute an inline script, which isn't allowed by your CSP. (You've included "unsafe-inline" which would normally allow it, but the SHA causes that to be ignored; see the last sentence in the error message.)

So that's what that hash is, and that's what inline script is. I can just include the hash in my CSP directives. Thanks, Evan. If you post this as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

From the error message, it looks like you're trying to execute an inline script, which isn't allowed by your CSP.
You've included "unsafe-inline" which would normally allow it, but the SHA causes that to be ignored; see the last sentence in the error message.
